# How to download an MTOM attachment in VB6

Tags: web-services, vb6, mtom

Please, someone can show me an example about how to download an MTOM attachment and save it to disk using VB6?

At the moment I am able to get a response from my ws, using this code:

```
Dim objDom As Object
Dim objXmlHttp As Object
Dim strRet As String
Dim intPos1 As Integer
Dim intPos2 As Integer
On Error GoTo Err_PW
' Create objects to DOMDocument and XMLHTTP
Set objDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

'Set objXmlHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP40
' Load XML
objDom.async = False
objDom.loadXML XmlBody

' Open the webservice
objXmlHttp.Open "POST", AsmxUrl, False
' Create headings
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", SoapActionUrl

' Send XML command
objXmlHttp.Send (objDom.xml)
' Get all response text from webservice
strRet = objXmlHttp.responseText
```

But from this point I don't know how to proceed to grab the MTOM attachment.

This is what return from ws:

```
--uuid:0b9372cf-63bb-484f-87f3-7bedfaa776fb
Content-Id: <rootpart*0b9372cf-63bb-484f-87f3-7bedfaa776fb@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body><ns2:getContentStreamResponse xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/">
<ns2:contentStream>
<ns2:length>2572861</ns2:length>
<ns2:mimeType>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document</ns2:mimeType>
<ns2:filename>SF-MASTER - SDTC.docx</ns2:filename>
<ns2:stream>
<xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:4b7c8c60-fc9e-4da8-92fc-aa8c2fdfb401@example.jaxws.sun.com"/></ns2:stream>
</ns2:contentStream>
</ns2:getContentStreamResponse>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
--uuid:0b9372cf-63bb-484f-87f3-7bedfaa776fb
Content-Id: <4b7c8c60-fc9e-4da8-92fc-aa8c2fdfb401@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

PK
31/05/2018 10:04:06: UUID documento: 0b9372cf-63bb-484f-87f3-7bedfaa776fb
31/05/2018 10:04:06: Tag finale: --uuid:0b9372cf-63bb-484f-87f3-7bedfaa776fb--
31/05/2018 10:04:06: lunghezza documento: 2572861
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Hoping it wasn't you that marked my answer as not useful? Not sure why it wouldn't be useful. Did you try it and have an issue or not understand why it works? A comment seems more appropriate in any case

Comment: Thank you dbmitch. It was not me to downvote your reply. Probably some troll. I'm sorry

Comment: Appreciated - and thank you. I've seen it before and never understand why. It must be something personal as it does cost them 2 points on their own too. Usually an explanation. Good luck on your endeavours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Use this as a guide](http://www.ericphelps.com/scripting/samples/BinaryDownload/) and modify your code to save the returned file data as a binary file.

**Add to top of function**

```
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

Dim varByteArray, ado
Dim strFile as String
```

**After you send the request insert this code**

```
If objXmlHttp.Status <> "200" Then
    Exit Function
End If

' Pull this from returned header data
strFile = "SF-MASTER - SDTC.docx"

' get file contents
varByteArray = objXmlHttp.ResponseBody

Set objXmlHttp= Nothing

'Now save the binary file
On Error Resume Next
Set ado = Nothing
Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
ado.Type = adTypeBinary
ado.Open
ado.Write varByteArray
ado.SaveToFile strFile, adSaveCreateOverWrite
ado.Close
```